# Does convergence of density imply convergence of parameter?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $f_n$ be the density of a normal distribution, with mean and variance $m_n, \sigma_n^2$. If the densities converge, $f_n \rightarrow f$, do $m_n$ and $\sigma_n$ converge?

I have so far been able to deduce that if $f_n$ converge, then $m_n$ and $\sigma_n$ must be bounded.

Comment: In what sense of convergence are we to understand $f_n\to f$?

Comment: Pointwise, almost surely.

Comment: Well, $\log f_n(x)$ is a quadratic function of $x$, for almost all $x$, with quadratic term $-x^2/(2\sigma_n^2)$, so you should be able to get convergence of $\sigma_n$ without trouble.  The a.e. problem can be handled by (I suppose) integrating $\log f_n(x)$ over 3 disjoint intervals, which gives you enough to fit the parameters.